# Game Center Crashing App on iOS 9.2

Tags: ios, swift

I have been getting several crash reports coming in on Xcode in regards to iOS 9.2.1 and my app crashing on the following line.

```
gameSettings.setHighScore(localPlayerScore!.value, highScore: gameSettings.getHighScore())
```

That line is a part of the following method in my GameViewController

```
func syncGameCenterHighScore() {
    if GKLocalPlayer.localPlayer().authenticated == true {
        let leaderBoardRequest = GKLeaderboard()
        leaderBoardRequest.identifier = "game"

        leaderBoardRequest.loadScoresWithCompletionHandler { (scores, error) -> Void in
            if (error != nil) {
                print("Error: \(error!.localizedDescription)")
            } else if (scores != nil) {
                let localPlayerScore = leaderBoardRequest.localPlayerScore
                gameSettings.setHighScore(localPlayerScore!.value, highScore: gameSettings.getHighScore())
            }
        }
    }
}
```

GameSettings getHighScore()

```
func getHighScore() -> Int64 {
    return  NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().objectForKey("highScore")?.longLongValue ?? 0
}
```

I have been unable to replicate the issue. Ive tried:

- Signed in to game center no prior score
- Signed out of game center no prior score
- Signed in game center prior score
- Signed out of game center prior score
- New game game center account no prior score.

I believe that the issue may possibly be coming from my getHighScore() method and it failing to convert to int64.

Comment: You can't reproduce it?

Answer (score 1):

I'd get rid of that forced unwrapped localPlayerScore variable with optional binding (or whatever you prefer), and then see if you still run into issues.

I'm not familiar with Game Center, by unless the scores variable you check is the same as leaderBoardRequest.localPlayerScore then your localPlayerScore could be coming back as nil in a certain case. Like if the app has never been ran on the device before possibly?

Answer (score 0):

This is how I accomplished this in my game.

How I authenticated the user:

```
func authenticateLocalPlayer(){

    let localPlayer = GKLocalPlayer.localPlayer()

    localPlayer.authenticateHandler = {(scene, error) -> Void in
        if error == nil {

            //If GameCenter login is successful
            if GKLocalPlayer.localPlayer().authenticated{
                //Checks if users that had highscores before the leaderboards were implemented, and stores saves it to leaderboards.
                if self.gameCenterAvailable == true && GKLocalPlayer.localPlayer().authenticated {

                    let high = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().integerForKey("highscore")

                    self.saveHighscore(high)

                    NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setBool(true, forKey: "savedHighest")
                }
            }
        } else {
            self.gameCenterAvailable = false
        }
    }
}
```

How I saved the highscore:

```
func saveHighscore(userScore: Int) {

    //check if user is signed in
    if GKLocalPlayer.localPlayer().authenticated {

        let scoreReporter = GKScore(leaderboardIdentifier: "xYOUR_LEADERBOARD_ID_HEREx") //leaderboard id here

        scoreReporter.value = Int64(userScore) //score variable here (same as above)

        let scoreArray: [GKScore] = [scoreReporter]

        GKScore.reportScores(scoreArray, withCompletionHandler: nil)
    }
}
```

When I created my app I didn't have leaderboards so I implemented this after the game was made.  Originally the highscore was only stored locally in NSUserDefaults.

So what I did to implement this was once the user opens the app and is signed in to game center.  It checks NSUserDefaults for the current Highscore and saves it to GameCenter so that the leaderboard is updated with the user's local highscore each time the app is open.  This also allows users to play without internet access and still have their scores displayed on the leaderboards once they reconnect at a later date.

Later on once the user dies or it's game over I check the NSUserDefaults value of the users highscore and compare it to their score for that round of my game.  If their new score is higher then you run the saveHighscore function.

Edit: Also, Just out of curiosity is your app actually using any of features implemented/only available in iOS 9.2?  If it's not you can lower the requirements of your app to iOS 8.0 allowing your app to be available to significantly more users, with literally no impact on your app what so ever.